# How to create different accounts in Substrate?

Tags: account, nodes, client, frontend

I would like to build a blockchain with Substrate where people can trade with products. They can log in in web, where they can see only their balances and products.I created private/public keypairs to some users. Adding these keys to keystore, modified customSpec.json with adding keys to aura and grandpa. I modified the chain_spec as well.
I still see the predefined accounts.
Besides that I have some doubt. Every user who want to use my blockchain has to start a new node? As for log in, how can I solve users can log in to the app and see only their balances?

I checked all tutorial which is accessable on substrate.io. I red a lot of posts, blogs, but these question are a dark spot for me. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the newly generated keys to node chainspec.rs file in your desired environment spec. Then you need to create the chainspec.json from that after that you will be able to use that.

Reference link: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L39-L125